testing coefficients in multiple linear regression
I apologise if question is trivial, but I could not find the solution. Assume, we are dealing with a multiple linear regression with iid Normal noise. In the book Testing Statistical Hypotheses by Romano and Lehman (p.193 in second edition) it was shown that z-test for testing coefficients is UMP unbiased test. Therefore, the authors considered the case a known variance.
Could someone, please, suggest a good source of the proof for the case of unknown variance, i.e. for t-test in multiple linear regression?
